# Terminal always on top, including on top of fullscreen applications

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to keep gnome-terminal on top of all the applications, even when I have something in full screen.

I already have always on top checked for the terminal, but if I run something in fullscreen it doesn't stay on top of that.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex I edited the post after the comment.

Comment: Ah, ok retracted my vote.